# CSS and JS Multi-Image Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built myself a CSS/JS image modal / lightbox (as others have done previously, it's based on the W3Schools tutorial - http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) however mine allows me to have multiple images on a single page reusing the same modal div, it allows me to size images by their container and then show the full size image when clicked.

Issue 1 - The images aren't centered in the modal (now fixed)

Issue 2 - The image pops up as intended until I add the zoom animation transition. then the image zooms in one location on the page (to the right and below center) and then pops into the correct location in the middle of the modal. I feel like I'm missing something really simple with the positioning? 
Can anyone help me find a simple solution just using CSS and Javascript?  or point me to a far more elegant solution for the whole thing?

https://codepen.io/r3dg3cko/pen/ZLryQG

```js
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.modal {
z-index:1;
display:none;
padding-top:10px;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
}

.modal-content{
margin: auto;
display: block;
max-width: 50%;
}


.modal-hover-opacity {
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
}

.modal-hover-opacity:hover {
opacity:0.60;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
}


.close {
text-decoration:none;float:right;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;color:white
}
.container1 {
width:200px;
display:inline-block;
}
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTczNTI2ODUwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTU0NTIzMw@@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,674,1000_AL_.jpg" style="max-width:100%;cursor:pointer"
 onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity">
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUyNzk3MjA1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTE1Njg2MQ@@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,674,1000_AL_.jpg" style="max-width:100%;cursor:pointer" 
    onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity">
  </div>

  <div class="container1">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM0MDgwNjMyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTg3NzAzMw@@._V1_.jpg" style="max-width:100%;cursor:pointer" 
    onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity">
  </div>

  <div class="container1">
    <img src="http://www.filmosphere.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Iron-Man-3-affiche1-300x400.jpg" style="max-width:100%;cursor:pointer" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity">
  </div>


<div id="modal01" class="modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
  <span class="close">&times;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img id="img01" style="max-width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks - Rob

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to `.modal-content`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, as below I fixed it with 

.modal-content{
margin: auto;
display: block;
    position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

But now the animation is off to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your div.container1 inside a div and `text-align:center` it

```
<div class="center">
...//div.container1
</div
```

CSS

```
.center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Height of the fourth image is less than other image height that is why it is out of proportion.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ypzfawt8/

Comment: Thanks, the problem did seem to be the alignment within the container.  I tried your text-align: center; solution but it didn't work for me but I added the following to  .modal-content;
.modal-content{
margin: auto;
display: block;
    position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

this has fixed the final position of the image to be centered but now the zoom  transformation starts off to the right and the animation jumps.